# Can you use fs (writeFile) and exec with Google App Engine?

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created an express server, which also writes some text into a file I have in the project directory and executes a cmd command. Locally, it works, but if I deploy it to App Engine and try to make a request I get error 500.

If there isn't a way to do this, what could I do instead of it? I guess for fs, storing it in Cloud Storage, but I don't know about exec-

The code:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { exec } = require('child_process');
var fs = require('fs')


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
module.exports = app

app.post("/", (req,res) =>{ 
    console.log("Get from /"); 
    console.log(req.body.data)
  
  
    fs.writeFileSync('../log.txt', req.body.data);

    exec('npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli',
        (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            }
            else{
              var addr = fs.readFileSync('../address.txt','utf8')
              res.send(addr);
            }
        })
  res.send(req.body.data);
                            });

// starting the server
app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('listening on port 8080');
});
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For App Engine Standard, you can't write to the local file system. You can write to `/tmp` which is a temporary directory. All files in this directory are stored in your instance's RAM which means you lose the file when the instance goes down (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-temp-files))

For App Engine Flexible, you can write to local disk but the disk is re-initialized whenever the VM is (re)started (see [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments))

Best thing would be to write to cloud storage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you maybe know what should I do about executing commands (with exec)?