# Node JS - Schedule MySQL back-up and send it by e-mail using Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, nodemailer

I am trying to build a NodeJS script to save a mySQL database, send it to me by e-mail as an attachement (the file is about 1MB), and I want to schedule the whole thing to run once a week. So far my script runs perfectly when run locally. I've set up the scheduling to run once every minute as a testing purpose.

I am struggling when trying to make it run on google cloud. The deployment went without issue, but then I only see in the logs `Saving Database...` so the scheduling part works fine, but I don't see the `Dump File OK` so I am assuming there is something wrong with mysqldump, but no error message. I didn't do anything specific with GCS, should I have ?

Thanks

```js
require("dotenv").config();
const mysqldump = require("mysqldump");
const fs = require("fs");
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var cron = require("node-cron");

async function saveDatabase() {
  console.error("Saving Database...");

  // dump the result straight to a file
   try {
    await mysqldump({
      connection: {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PWD,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
      },
      dumpToFile: "./dump.sql",
    });
    console.error("Dump File OK");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  // mail server config and authentication
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.hostinger.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_ADDRESS,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PWD,
    },
  });

  console.error("Mail Server OK");

  // mail options
  var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.MAIL_ADDRESS,
    to: "************@gmail.com",
    subject: "Sauvegarde Base de Données",
    text: "Base de donnée sauvegardée.",
    attachments: [
      {
        path: "./dump.sql",
      },
    ],
  };

  // send the e-mail
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.error("E-mail sent");
    }
  });
}

cron.schedule("* * * * *", () => saveDatabase());
```

I have added a try/catch around my mysqldump and indeed I got this error message :

```
Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open './dump.sql'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:590:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (node:fs:2202:35)
    at /workspace/node_modules/mysqldump/dist/cjs.js:883:20
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /workspace/node_modules/mysqldump/dist/cjs.js:44:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/workspace/node_modules/mysqldump/dist/cjs.js:40:12)
    at main (/workspace/node_modules/mysqldump/dist/cjs.js:855:12)
    at saveDatabase (/workspace/index.js:12:11)
    at Task._execution (/workspace/index.js:62:34) {
```

So that's an issue when trying to save the file so as I thought there's probably something I should have done differently like set up google storage.
Since I don't need the file to be save on GCS, I could save the result of mysqldump in a variable instead than in a file, but then I don't know how to send that as an attachment of an e-mail without creating a file at some point.

EDIT : Solution without needing to write into a file

```js
async function saveDatabase() {
  // dump the result
  const result = await mysqldump({
    connection: {
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_PWD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DB,
    },
  });

  // mail server config and authentication
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.hostinger.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_ADDRESS,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PWD,
    },
  });

  // mail options
  var mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.MAIL_ADDRESS,
    to: "*********@gmail.com",
    subject: "Sauvegarde Base de Données",
    text: "Base de donnée sauvegardée.",
    attachments: [
      {
        filename: "data.sql",
        content: result.dump.data,
      },
      {
        filename: "schema.sql",
        content: result.dump.schema,
      },
    ],
  };

  // send the e-mail
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.error("E-mail sent");
    }
  });
}

cron.schedule("0 0 * * Sunday", () => saveDatabase());
```

EDIT 2 :
Just an additional edit since node-cron doesn't work well on google cloud, but you can just use Google Cloud Scheduler that works pretty much the same way.

Comment: `make it run on google cloud` Google Cloud is a platform with multiple products, in which one are you running this? Where is the MySQL database? In a VM or Cloud SQL? You're missing some details here

Comment: The app is on google app engine, the MySQL is on Hostinger. I don't believe there is an issue connecting to the database since it works fine when run locally.

Comment: I see the error and it is expected. App Engine does not allow writing in "local" (actually is the memory) Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73315738/can-you-use-fs-writefile-and-exec-with-google-app-engine as an option write to `/tmp` or writing to GCS and maybe send the link to the bucket in the mail

Comment: Thanks. I had a read at mysqldump doc and managed to do it differently by not actually using a file but instead saving the dump into a variable and letting nodemailer create the attachement file from the variable. But that's interesting to know that I could use ```/tmp```if required. Maybe I'll try it this way later for learning purposes.